# Watching K8s container resource usage

Tags: kubernetes, client-go

I am using `client-go` to read K8s container resource usage using the `Get` method of the core client-go client, but re-fetching the K8s object on an interval seems like the wrong approach. What is the better approach for periodically fetching status changes to a K8s container?

Answer (score 2):

You would use an Informer which runs an API watch that receives push updates from kube-apiserver. Though that said, you might find it easier to use one of the operator support frameworks like Kubebuilder, or at least directly use the underlying controller-runtime library as raw client-go can be a little gnarly to configure stable informers. Doable either way though.